# `express` object from apollo-server-lambda context is undefined

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, apollo-server, netlify, netlify-function

I am following [this guide](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/deployment/lambda/) to make my apollo server run with Netlify functions. It works fine for non authenticated requests, but I have problems when I need to read the headers.

The guide says that I can get the `req` from the `express` object as shown in this snippet.

```js
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  context: ({ event, context, express }) => ({
    headers: event.headers,
    functionName: context.functionName,
    event,
    context,
    expressRequest: express.req,
  }),
});
```

However, when I try this myself, I get an undefined `express`.
This is my code.

```
const { ApolloServer } = require("apollo-server-lambda");
const accountsGraphQL = require("./accounts.js");
const schema = require("./schema/index.js");

const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema,
  context: async ({ event, context, express }) => {
    console.log(express); // outputs undefined
    return {
      headers: event.headers,
      functionName: context.functionName,
      event,
      context: await accountsGraphQL.context(express.req), // errors `Context creation failed: Cannot read property 'req' of undefined`
    }
  },
  introspection: true,
  playground: true,
});

const handler = server.createHandler();

module.exports = { handler };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, I solved my problem by making another object that contains the `req` with the `headers` and `authorization`.

```js
const { ApolloServer } = require("apollo-server-lambda");
const accountsGraphQL = require("./accounts.js");
const schema = require("./schema/index.js");

const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema,
  context: async ({ event }) => {
    return await accountsGraphQL.context({
      req: { headers: { authorization: event.headers.authorization } },
    });
  },
  introspection: true,
  playground: true,
});

const handler = server.createHandler();

module.exports = { handler };
```